# How to downvote, close or flag proposal documentation tags

Tags: discussion, tags, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-proposals

How can I raise concerns about proposed topics? I see ones that there are various places for things to go or just be dropped:

- [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics) Too generic (sorry, not sorry). This one should be associated with the language, but it's not specified which one
- [entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework), [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core), [linq-to-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq-to-sql), [wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf), [workflow-foundation-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workflow-foundation-4), [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf), [linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq) should belong inside of the .NET framework
- [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) Why? which IDE?
- [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) [properties-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/properties-file) [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) [servlet-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servlet-filters) [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh) [windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) [yii2-advanced-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii2-advanced-app) Burn these

Comment: There is also a problem of overlap within tags. Not an issue with questions, because we allow multiple tags, but rather a problem as I see it with Documentation where you have C# examples both under the [c#] tag and the [.net] tag. Which one is more appropriate? Should we even *be* documenting a [.net] tag, since they keep telling us the Killer Feature of Documentation is *examples*, and you can't give sample code for ".NET" without picking a language. Which one do you pick?

Comment: @CodyGray in pirvate Beta, putting examples for C#, VB and F# was the chosen practice for .NET topics - still, I agree having bot C# and .NET is problematic because it calls for duplicates

Comment: there is an overlap but i feel the c# should focus on language features and .net on the libraries.

Comment: yeah, but this would mean deleting most of the content currently located in .NET - while in private Beta, we already had big dicussions how to proceed but we continued as it is now because there wasn't a real consens

Comment: I think overlaps aren't entirely problematic, as long as its not completely redundant.  For example, we have a VBA tag as well as excel-vba and powerpoint-vba etc.  While vba is consistent through each of the tags, the implementation and methods/properties can be quite different among the specific usages

Comment: Just a note here about that you wrote that [tag:entity-framework] should belong to the tag .NET Framework. I think it shouldn't, since it's now a different "product" that you can install via NuGet, also a quote from Wikipedia: _was a part of .NET Framework, but from Entity framework version 6 it is separated from .NET framework._

Comment: @kayess ha! Like people ever ask about pre-6 examples...

Comment: @kayess theres asp.net flavors in the .net-framework

Comment: @DanielA.White what do you mean by flavors?

Comment: @kayess different types - theres web forms and mvc.

Comment: @DanielA.White I think I'm loosing your point here, what's the connection between EF and webforms/mvc ? You can freely use NHibernate for instance :p

Comment: @kayess i feel that ef is more core than nhibernate as it has microsoft backing IMO

Comment: @DanielA.White gotcha, however my intent was to shed light on that it's not _core_ anymore :)

Comment: I really want to see this happen. There is a proposal for a [`date`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/date) tag. Not a date topic in a language, but a whole tag, just for dates. That tag barely deserves to be a tag on SO main...

Comment: This demonstrate why the current *status quo* of the tags isn't sustainable in the long run. These aberrations were predicted long ago, but everyone brushed it off... now we got a problem to solve and lack the means to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't agree more. Add also to your list [antlr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antlr) and [antlr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antlr4). Documentation already has a feature that can handle versions internally.

As a participant in private beta I can say that there are some grey areas, and the .NET umbrella is one of them. As you see under .NET Framework documentation, there have been proposals about creating topic such as [.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Core) there. If I am not mistaken a topic, entity-framework, is already included in the .NET Framework documentation. However things such as C#, vd and WPF are still unclear, if they belong under .NET Framework or as a separate topic. The upcoming feature of having a language switch inside documentation examples (as [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network) does) maybe clarify these things.

It would be good if there was a mechanism that users can deny a documentation tag. Something like Up / Down vote for a proposal. I think this is a widely-used model on SO, e.g. moderator elections. The drawback of this it is that it may take a lot of time before a new documentation tag is created. Also how can we reach a consensus? Where should the voting stop?

Another suggestion would be to allow only users that have participated enough in documentation to propose or commit to tag. This way we can be sure that they know the rules / philosophy.

Comment: it seems gated but only with one upvote in the tag.