# What about merging antlr and antlr4 documentation tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, documentation, tag-alias-request

As a member of the documentation private beta I was there long enough to understand well (or at least I thought so) the concepts of documentation.

There have been a lot of discussions / debates on how the content should be classified. In some cases there is not a clear solution but in others there is. (see also [How to downvote, close or flag proposal documentation tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328414/how-to-downvote-close-or-flag-proposal-documentation-tags/328484#328484))

What it bugs me is the [antlr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antlr) and [antlr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antlr4) tags, as I previously said

> Documentation already has a feature that can handle versions internally.

I am an `antlr` user and I know that there are a lot and significant differences between v3 and v4. However this does not justify to have different documentation tags for every version `antlr` makes. Of course someone can say that, `antlr` covers a more general concept than `antlr4`. If we continue to move in the same direction we will have to create documentation tags for [antlr3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antlr3) and [antlr2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antlr2).

So why we are keeping both tags or better why in the first place we 'allowed' this to tags to be created in the documentation?

Having those in mind, a week ago I tried to [move](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/76537) content from the `antlr4` documentation to `antlr`, however as you can see my 'change' was rejected. One of the comments I received is

> Are you trying to move this from [antrl4] to [antlr]? If so, that's incorrect, as examples illustrate features specific to v4.

And I am here to ask, **isn't this purpose of versions in the documentation?**

Going one step further, would it be reasonable to create tag aliases and point every `antlr*` tag to `antlr`?

**Additional resources**

- [A similar question regarding `java8` documentation tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags)

Comment: Awww... I just noticed the change and I disagree with it - v3 and v4 are totally different, think like the difference between Perl 5 and Perl 6. Now all my examples are broken as I assumed v4 and I'll have to add version tags. I assume long term this will be a big mess - let's see how it gets.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I agree with you that the documentation right now needs some refinement. However I will disagree that having v3 and v4 or even v2 under the same documentation will be a problem. I know that the differences are significant, but versions can cover this. Also I think there is some overlapping, in some 'early steps' e.g installing and using antlr4 as standalone or via various IDEs.As you said lets see how it gets.

Comment: Damn it, you moved **the** example I most often refer to to the remarks section, and thus broke the links in several of my answers :( Mind reverting that? This is *the* single most useful example in the whole lexer topic, and I *really* need to have a direct link to that.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, I see your point there, especially if have a significant amount of links. However, I do not think that just "linking" justifies, this example. You can change your links and point them directly to the remarks section.

Comment: I'll do something else instead: I'll edit this example to expand it with some actual grammar that illustrates the rules (maybe later today if I have some time). This way it will become a real example and everyone wins. I agree with you that right now it doesn't *feel* like a real example, and I'll improve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.

As of now, antlr2, antlr3 and antlr4 all point to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/antlr

That tag could use a bit of cleanup.

Comment: Aww, those are *totally* different products that are vastly incompatible with each other - having a common documentation doesn't make much sense IMO. Do you think it's reasonable to try to shove everything together? Right now it's a mess.

Comment: Unless the products have little or no overlap in *functionality*, versioning within docs should suffice here @lucas. Perhaps post an answer detailing the problems you've observed?

Comment: They do have overlap, and also *major* differences. Let's see how it goes - right now there's a lot of content still to write, we'll see if the discrepancy between versions becomes a problem later on, I may as well be wrong. While we're at it, could you just uppercase the docs title to "ANTLR" please, as it's an acronym?

Comment: Done, @LucasTrzesniewski