# Broken documentation review link after tag merging

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

The [antlr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antlr) and [antlr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antlr4) documentation tags were merged a couple of weeks ago. ([meta resource](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332539/2279200)).

However as I see it, this broke some of the review change link. Those broken links are about changes made in [antlr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antlr4), which later was merged in [antlr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antlr).

Navigating to those reviews, results to an `Oops` page

- [Introduction to antlr4](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/39431)
- [Introduction to ANTLR v4](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/40624)

<s>I have not verified this 100%, so I am tagging as [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) and not as a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug).</s>

Did anyone else encountered this case?

Comment: Happening for me, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest build.

Here's the bug:

[image: ?]